# Logic in getting users that is not a member of the group

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

What kind of logic is behind getting a list of users that is not a member of the selected group.
Or **get a list of users that is not in my contacts list**.

Using laravel I have came up with a code.

The code:

```
// I get all the uid of the members of the user group.
$members_list = GroupMembers::where('group_id', $group_id)->lists('uid');

// I compare it to the list of all users and get those that are not in the list
$nonMembers = Users:whereNotIn('uid', $members_list)->paginate(10);
```

But is this the most efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it really matters too much because they are both pretty simple queries so they shouldn't take too long.  It would probably take some experimenting to figure out which way is the fastest if you are really concerned about performance.

Here is a way you can do it using the query builder and table joins.  This will use one query, but because it's joining, it will probably take just about the same amount of time as using what you have already.  Also note that this won't allow you to traverse the collections like you usually would ($user->group->name for example would just become $user->name, which if there is a name column on your users table, something may get overwritten)

```
$users = DB::table('group_members')
    ->join('users','users.uid','=','group_members.uid')
    ->where('group_members.group_id', '<>', $group_id)
    ->paginate(10);
```

What you are doing now is pretty much exactly what eager loading is doing, except you are doing it by hand.  The correct way to do this is as follows and is probably your best solution, though it probably won't save you anything on performance.

```
$users = User::with(array('groupMembers' => function($query) use ($group_id)
{
    $query->where('group_id', '<>', $group_id);
}))->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

definitely not that best..
Assuming the relationship is

> Group members->has many->Users

you could to to use joins

DB::table('group_members')
    ->join('users','group_members.uid','<>','users.uid')